# EventEmiter from child to parent not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to pass a value (0) to a parent component, so I call a child component as follows:

```
<app-componentadduser [target]="target" *ngIf="opt==1" (newItemEvent)="changeOpt($event)"></app-componentadduser>
```

And the code for changeOpt:

```
changeOpt(newItem: number) {
    console.log(newItem)
    this.opt = newItem;
  }
```

On the child side,

```
@Input() target: string;
  @Output() newItemEvent = new EventEmitter<number>();
```

Then when a button is clicked, and after a process takes place:

```
this.newItemEvent.emit(0);
```

From the parent, I even try to console.log newItem (value is 0) but changeOpt is never executed.

I dont know what Im missing. I thought the *ngIf had something to do with it, but it doesn't.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Console.log is throwing this error:

> TypeError: ctx_r9.changeOpt is not a function. (In
> 'ctx_r9.changeOpt($event)', 'ctx_r9.changeOpt' is undefined)

Comment: I don't see a problem in the code you posted, as in: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eqsdhn so there must be something else that's making it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are just passing a number, try

```
(newItemEvent)="opt=$event"
```

Comment: that worked perfect. I still dont understand what was the issue

Answer (score 1):

first of all i do not know where do you call the this.newItemEvent.emit(0);

So its possible that there is problem with this method. You should call it for example on button or on some action. Everything else seems fine, but maybe i am blind :D

Anyway i created stackBlitz example with your output and everything works. Have a look.

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eventemitter-todo-t3by43?file=app%2Ftodos%2Fapp-parent.component.ts)

Comment: Daniel, I know, that's why Im totally lost, the code seems to be fine. The solution by PVG worked, but I still do not understand WHY it worked and my code doesn't: (newItemEvent)="opt=$event"

Comment: I am not at my pc now but i am srsly blind. I will have a look once more time and let you know with my ressult.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, its fine. I just would like to understand why my code does not work, and PVGs one does when passing just opt=$event instead of changeOpt($event). Its just weird. Thanks :)